# Embedding an anonymous function inside of another anonymous function

Tags: javascript

I have a hash called options. The problem that I'm facing is that `options['beforeOpen']` might already be a function, in which case I don't want to overwrite it.  I'd like to instead call it then call another function that needs to be called every time

In this example the method that needs to be called every time is `methodThatINeedToDo`. I thought the code below would accomplish this but it's not working as I expected.

```
function methodThatINeedToDo(){alert('maintenance');}

var options = {beforeOpen: function(){alert('first');}} 
if(typeof options['beforeOpen'] == "function"){
    options['beforeOpen'] = function(){options['beforeOpen'].call(); methodThatINeedToAddToDo();}
} else {
    options['beforeOpen'] = methodThatINeedToDo;
}
```

Comment: What problems do you have with this code? It seems worked for me.

Comment: why the options['beforeOpen'].call()? should not be options['beforeOpen']() ?

Comment: why even bother with this unflexible solution?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that *within* the function you're defining to override `options['beforeOpen']`, you're using `options['beforeOpen']`, which by that time has been overwritten!

You need to cache it and use the cached value within your new function:

```
var cachedBeforeOpen = options.beforeOpen;

if (typeof cachedBeforeOpen == "function") {
  options.beforeOpen = function() {
    cachedBeforeOpen.call();
    methodThatINeedToDo();
  };
} else {
  options.beforeOpen = methodThatINeedToDo;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Simply always call `methodThatINeedToDo`, since you want to and in there check to see if you should call your options method:

```
function methodThatINeedToDo(){
  options.beforeOpen && options.beforeOpen();
  alert('maintenance');
}
```

Answer (score 1):

That really smells like the wrong solution. Why not [Publish/Subscribe pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Publish%E2%80%93subscribe_pattern)?

Here's a little example: http://jsfiddle.net/ajyQH/

```
$(function() {

var yourObj = { yourFct : [] };


$('#btn').click(function() {
    yourObj.yourFct.push(function() {
        $('#testibert').append($('<p>').text('hallo'));
    });
});

$('#btn_exec').click(function() {
    var len = yourObj.yourFct.length;
    for(var i = 0; i < len; i++) {
      yourObj.yourFct[i]();
    }
});
});
```

Comment: Although this is a really good point, I don't have access to the part of the code that calls the method and it's not currently able to handle an array of functions. I really like this solution though, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

```
var oldCall = options['beforeOpen'];
var newCall = function(){
 oldCall(); 
 methodThatINeedToAddToDo();
};
options['beforeOpen'] = newCall;
```